# An unhandled exception occurred - Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-diagnostics

I have an Azure Website, and I'm looking at the most recent eventlog.xml file.  I see several errors that look like the following:

> An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated. Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/2036313205/ROOT Process ID: 8356 Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException Message: Could not create Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35. StackTrace: at System.Diagnostics.TraceUtils.GetRuntimeObject(String className, Type baseType, String initializeData) at System.Diagnostics.TypedElement.BaseGetRuntimeObject() at System.Diagnostics.ListenerElement.GetRuntimeObject() at System.Diagnostics.ListenerElementsCollection.GetRuntimeObject() at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.get_Listeners() at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.WriteLine(String message) at System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String message) at Microsoft.Web.Compilation.Snapshots.SnapshotHelper.TakeSnapshotTimerCallback(Object stateInfo) at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(Object state) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback() at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire() at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers() at System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback() InnerException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. StackTrace: at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultStartupInfoForCurrentRoleInstance() at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener..ctor()

1. Does this indicate that my IIS worker process is getting restarted?
2. Any clues on how to resolve this?  I haven't seen any issues as I use my site.. it could be because IIS is "handling" this issue as best it can, but this is news to me..

TIA

Comment: Which version of the Azure SDK are you using?

Comment: This looks like a callstack from a cloud service *WebRole*.  The DiagnosticMonitor is not applicable for Azure WebApps (formerly Websites).

Comment: Thanks @RickRainey, the only reference to "DiagnosticMonitor" I see in my app is for the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener.  I just commented that out, will see if that works...

Comment: @ewitkows Just following up on this to make sure you are unblocked.

Comment: @cory-fowler still investigating and actually pushing the recommended changes into production tomorrow AM.  Hoping to see this issue disappear at that time